# Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL OneDrive explorer javascript problem

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

I have some strange problem with onedrive explorer:

https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-explorer-js

I have configured my app credentials, have added the permissions:

Files.Read
Files.Read.All
offline_access
profile
Sites.Read.All
User.Read

and get this error:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root?expand=thumbnails,children(expand=thumbnails(select=large))
502
Bad Gateway

additional error text:

Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL.

I have tried with 3 different accounts.

Additionally, on graph explorer I have an error :
Must be authenticated to use '/drive' syntax (It gives my profile details and nothing else) from -

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Can somebody let me know what could be the problem?

Thank you !

Comment: With app credentials, why you want to call /me endpoint?

Comment: Hello @dev , this is in the code of Microsoft.  I am just trying to use it. 
Not sure if i gave the correct permissions in the app. I have tried different codes - error is the same. I am trying with personal accounts and don't have subscription for Azure.

Comment: Go it @vasilev. Not an issue. I would login to my personal account first, then will try the Graph API call in Microsoft Graph Explorer and see if i can repro the issue or not. Let me try that and will let you know as well.

Comment: Ok, i tried with my personal account, logged in via Microsoft Graph explorer,  made the following Graph API call, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children" - it works for me.

Comment: Also i tried the above Graph API call "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root?expand=thumbnails,children(expand=thumbnails(select=large))" and it works me. I am not getting any error.

Comment: Hm. I have tried this already in :
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

then login, then got:

"code": "unauthenticated",
        "message": "Must be authenticated to use '/drive' syntax",

/me is working fine with same token from same place - gives my details.

so this means problem is in my accounts.. but what exactly.
i can provide the link to  my website with odauth to try if you want..

Comment: Glad that you tried above and it worked for '/me' and fails on another; so you can able to isolate the issue out of the sample. Sounds like an issue with account(s). You may want to check with Microsoft support to see if they can able to find/diagnose and fix, incase if there is an issue.

Comment: Hi . This is not possible :) the account is from free ones with no subscription . I have already tried... If I don't pay, nobody care.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in the azure subscription, not in any of the accounts. I have created new subscription and all is fine. Seems that this use case or test cannot be done for free.
Thanks for the collaboration :)